# Javascript, проблема с условным оператором

Tags: javascript

Почему код работает не правильно?

Если указанное время больше 6 или меньше 12, то выводится "Доброе утро", если указанное время больше 12 или меньше 18, то выводится "Добрый день", в остальные случаи "добрый вечер".

```js
let time = prompt( 'какое у вас время?' );

if (time > 6  || time < 12 ) {
   alert( 'Доброе утро' );
} else if (time >  12 || time < 18 ) {
   alert( 'Добрый день' );
} else {
   alert( 'Добрый вечер' );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для указания каких-то промежутков нужно использовать логическое И, а не логическое ИЛИ. Если вы пишете "больше 6 или меньше 12", то истиной будут любые числа.

Если ввести 19, то это число проходит по условию `time > 6`, если же 4, например, то оно проходит по условию `time < 12`. Также нужно не забывать про `>=`, а то пропускается число.

В итоге имеется:

```js
let time = prompt( 'какое у вас время?' );

if (time > 6  && time < 12 ) {
   alert( 'Доброе утро' );
} else if (time >=  12 && time < 18 ) {
   alert( 'Добрый день' );
} else {
   alert( 'Добрый вечер' );
}
```

Comment: cпасибо вам большое,очень сильно помогли

Comment: @Jquery У вас мало репутации, чтобы поставить ответу плюс, но как автор ответа вы можете просто поставить галку как знак принятого ответа.